# heteroscedastic uncertainty

Tags: heteroscedasticity, measurement-error

I am majoring in economics and I am reading [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167629602000073) paper by Crossley & Kennedy (2002). It discusses the reliability of self-assessed health status (that is "In general, would you say that your health is excellent? very good? good? fair? poor?"). They determine that self-assessed health status has considerable measurement error. For example, people change their response when asked about their health twice. I am reading the discussion section of the paper and have the following questions regarding to the second paragraph bellow:

- I cannot understand the part that it says "this uncertainty is, at minimum, heteroscedastic.
- Additionally, when it says "the degree of uncertainty", does it refer to the variance of the measurement error or the expectation (mean) of the measurement error?
- It says the uncertainty being correlated in mean with with socio-economic characteristics will be a problem for studies that use self-assessed health status. Why? Isn't measurement error only a problem when it is in the explanatory variable? (considering attenuation bias)
- Finally, if we say that self-assessed health status is correlated with weather fluctuations (that is on sunny days people feel healthier), how could this be an issue in empirical research?

Thank you very much for your help. Even if you can't reply every question, it could help a lot if you provide any help. If you add mathematic notation, it may help me even more.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to cv, Alonso! I also find the terminology "heteroskedastic uncertainty" quite strange... A suggestion to make your question accessible to vision impaired readers: if you have the possibility to copy paste the highlighted text from that paper, you could add it as an image description :-)